# Karate UI: How to run multiple scenarios in parallel in a single feature file

Tags: karate

I am running multiple scenarios in a single feature file using karate UI.
All scenarios are running in sequence but in my case I need to run those scenarios in parallel.
We can run feature files in parallel, but is there any way to run all scenarios in a single feature file parallelly?